# Remove get parameter in URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My URLs looks like this: `www.example.com/?content=somefile.php`.

The pattern is: always `www.example.com/?content=`, than a file like `somefile.php` and sometimes some more get parameters.

Is there a way to use `www.example.com/somefile.php` instead of `www.example.com/?content=somefile.php`?

I already tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?content=$1 [L]
```

but I'm getting the following error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at www.example.com Port 80

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to avoid internal server error:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if request is not for image/css/js files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
# skip if we already have ?content= in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)content= [NC]
# rewrite to ?content=
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?content=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Seems to work, but please say, what is this code doing? Why do you count format suffixes?

Comment: I've added inline comments for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)content= [NC] #taken from anubhava's code
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?content=$1 [L]
```

And you shouldn't directly read *?content* value, it might be dangerous.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. Any other idea? Why is it dangerous to directly read the `?content` value?

Comment: If you doing something like; `file_get_contents($_GET['content']);` hackers can read sensitive files like .htaccess, /etc/ files, or maybe even for HTTP calls.

Comment: And the problem is infinite loop, as @anubhava said, if you skip when we have ?content= in the URL, it will work fine. My fault in code :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. There're still some "bugs", I'm working on it.

Comment: I know it's of-topic but can you say me, does my code allow "hackers can read sensitive files"? Here's my code: https://codeshare.io/2WddVE

Comment: Yes. If hacker pass ../../../../../../etc/shadow, it will print /etc/shadow file contents to the page. He can also view any config files. Check for dot, slash, back-slash, and some other special characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133332/discussion-between-mehmet-cagri-ari-and-user7128548).